# UIWebView and tons of memory issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

This is the second time i am facing this very strange problem, that i am really wondering how Apple is letting this to happen without fixing this thing .

On the `iPad Air` , if you open a `UIWebView`, and simply load a site into it, you sometimes get a memory warnings , what does it means sometimes ? well, it is probably about 60-70% of the time, seems that it depends on the site you open. (maybe with big size images).
In most of time, after a while the app is crashing because `"memory pressure"`(said a pop window).

To be sure, you can just start a new project, and the only thing you will do is to open a web view, and you will see you get this warnings.

So , i don't know if there are some properties that can be changed , in order to eliminate the warnings, or there is a way to see what exactly is causing them , but any thought on this will be very helpful.

Just to be sure ,this is how i open some website :

```
UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, contentView.frame.size.width, contentView.frame.size.height)];
webview.opaque = NO;
webview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
NSURL *websiteUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:currentLink];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:websiteUrl];
[webview setDelegate:self];
webview.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=NO;
 webview.scalesPageToFit = YES;
[webview loadRequest:urlRequest];
[contentView addSubview:webview];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue , if we didn't release memory before the memory over limit , iOS will shut down  your app ,so sweet....

I tried many solutions but they couldn't release all of memory.

Try this, this way could release most memory I ever tried.

```
[self.yourUIWebView release];
```